# jQuery ajax upload file in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a file in my view

```
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" size="23" />
</form>
```

and an ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%=Url.Action("JsonSave","Survey")  %>',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: "multipart/mixed",
    data: {
        Id: selectedRow.Id,
        Value: 'some date was added by the user here :))'
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

but there is no file in the **Request.Files**. Whats wrong with the ajax request?

Comment: json can't upload files like this.  Better to use the browsers default upload behavior.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

[Upload files using AJAX in ASP.Net MVC](http://ajeeshms.github.io/articles/upload-files-using-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Things have changed since HTML5

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('uploader').onsubmit = function () {
    var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    //Iterating through each files selected in fileInput
    for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        //Appending each file to FormData object
        formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
    }
    //Creating an XMLHttpRequest and sending
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/Home/Upload');
    xhr.send(formdata);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult Upload()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i]; //Uploaded file
        //Use the following properties to get file's name, size and MIMEType
        int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
        string fileName = file.FileName;
        string mimeType = file.ContentType;
        System.IO.Stream fileContent = file.InputStream;
        //To save file, use SaveAs method
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/")+ fileName ); //File will be saved in application root
    }
    return Json("Uploaded " + Request.Files.Count + " files");
}
```

***EDIT* : The HTML**

```
<form id="uploader">
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the view? the HTML.. to this answer.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to bind the uploaded files into a model?

Comment: This does not work in IE.  IE passes the user's full local path in the file.FileName parameter, so you'll need to Path.GetFileName(file.FileName) to be safe. Otherwise fantastic answer.  Big help, thank you.

Comment: links in this answer (and the other one in the comment) are broken

Comment: Imagine that I need '/MyArea/Home/Upload' instead of '/Home/Upload'. How could I do it? If I try this way I get a 404 despite stating the right area, controller and action name.

Comment: I am using an area as well and just put "Controller/Action" and it worked.

Comment: How to pass additional parameters with this request?

Comment: Request.Files is not available in MVC.Core. Any alternative for MVC.Core ??

Comment: @NareshRavlani For MVC Core check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44174182/6870933

Comment: You can get complete code example here: 
http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/JQuery-Ajax-File-Upload-in-NET-MVC-With-Code-Examples

Answer (score 55):

AJAX file uploads are now possible by passing a `FormData` object to the `data` property of the `$.ajax` request.

As the OP specifically asked for a jQuery implementation, here you go:

```html
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Action("JsonSave", "Survey")" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" size="23" /><br />
    <button>Upload!</button>
</form>
```

```js
$('#upload').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the standard form submission

    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: new FormData(this),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.UploadedFileCount + ' file(s) uploaded successfully');
        },
        error: function(xhr, error, status) {
            console.log(error, status);
        }
    });
});
```

```csharp
public JsonResult Survey()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        var file = Request.Files[i];
        // save file as required here...
    }
    return Json(new { UploadedFileCount = Request.Files.Count });
}
```

More information on [FormData at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you!  Best answer I have found on SEVERAL questions.

Comment: Came here specifically looking for jQuery solution and was a little disappointed in seeing that the response marked as Answered only used vanilla JavaScript. Your solution is great and works very well for me. Thanks very much :)

Comment: Note that if you don't select a file, you still seem to get a single file in the array, with ContentLength = 0

Comment: @Savage  : tested in 2020 / chrome / asp net core mvc : file is null when you don't select anything. Anyway, the answer is a really clean file upload integration with razor and MVC controller

Comment: does not call $('#upload').submit(function. Directly going to controller and also changes the page

Comment: @BalasubramanianRamamoorthi in that case you've got something wrong in your HTML or JS. I'd suggest starting a new question about your specific case as this example above is valid and correct.

Comment: I put $('#upload').submit function is separte js file. After putting in cshtml document ready it worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can't upload files via ajax, you need to use an iFrame or some other trickery to do a full postback.  This is mainly due to security concerns.

[Here's a decent write-up including a sample project](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/11/24/jquery-ajax-uploader-plugin-with-progress-bar/) using SWFUpload and ASP.Net MVC by Steve Sanderson.  It's the first thing I read getting this working properly with Asp.Net MVC (I was new to MVC at the time as well), hopefully it's as helpful for you.

Comment: That's not true; you can send the form data via ajax.

Comment: @kehrk: With the new FormData and File objects in HTML5, you can indeed upload files via AJAX. Try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications.

Answer (score 1):

I have a sample like this on vuejs version: v2.5.2

```
<form action="url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" class="image_0" name="FilesFront" ref="FilesFront" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" class="image_1" name="FilesBack" ref="FilesBack" />
    </div>
</form>
<script>
Vue.component('v-bl-document', {
    template: '#document-item-template',
    props: ['doc'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            document: this.doc
        };
    },
    methods: {
        submit: function () {
            event.preventDefault();

            var data = new FormData();
            var _doc = this.document;
            Object.keys(_doc).forEach(function (key) {
                data.append(key, _doc[key]);
            });
            var _refs = this.$refs;
            Object.keys(_refs).forEach(function (key) {
                data.append(key, _refs[key].files[0]);
            });

            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                url: url,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    //do something
                },

            });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: bloody hell, I've spent the better part of 2 days wrapping my head around this problem, and here's a solution. Is it possible to modelbind the form though?

Answer (score 0):

If you posting form using ajax then you can not 
send image using $.ajax method,
you have to use  classic xmlHttpobject  method for saving image,
other alternative of it use submit type  instead of  button