# Uploading Files with ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I am working on exposing some REST-based services via ASP.NET MVC 3. These services will be hit via JQuery as well as a Windows Phone Silverligh app. I know how to interact with a typical service. For instance, I currently have ones like the followng:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddComment(string username, string comment)
{
  // Do stuff
  return Json(new { message = "Success" });
}
```

I want to expose a REST-based service that allows users to upload a file. The trick here is that I also need to pass some data along with each file. However, I'm not sure how to do that. Every example I find only has just a file. But I'm not sure of

1. How to accept additional data
2. What to pass from JQuery.

Everything else I passed is just strings. However, in this I seem to have data serialized in binary format because of the file, and some string text. Because of that, I'm not sure what to do. Am I making sense?

Comment: Just to be clear, the sample code you posted is not RESTfull.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery ajax upload file in asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428296/jquery-ajax-upload-file-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I reviewed the "jQuery ajax upload file in asp.net mvc". In my opinion, this question is not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 4):

The signature for the action should just be:
   public ActionResult MyAction(string username, string comment, HttpPostedFileBase file1)
   { ... }

MVC binding should examine the request and match the form submission to the action based on the parameter names and types.

The clientside form must have enctype = "multipart/form-data" with method POST.

JQuery would just post the form with $("#form").submit().

Comment: What if I need to POST the image via the an $.ajax call?

Comment: @user70192, you cannot upload files using AJAX as explained in the duplicate post. So if you have to do this you could use a client side upload plugin. Or use the HTML5 File API.