# File upload using MVC 4 with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing web application using MVC 4 + VS 2012 + Framework 4.5.

I have three partial views, which are rendering dynamically, on my index page based on user action.

Out of three partial views, one partial view has `Upload File` functionality with some entry fields like textboxes.

Problem:

When user click on save button (which is present on the partial view itself). I want to save entry field into my database and stored uploaded file on shared folder.

I want to implement this using Ajax (After uploading the file and save data, user should be on the same view).

How can I implement the same? JQuery solution would be fine.

I have tried with `@Ajax.BeginForm` but after uploading of file, full post back happen.

Comment: HTML5 may not be support with earlier/old browsers. kindly suggest something which support with old browsers.

Comment: [Ajax Multiple file upload script with Progress bar, Drag and Drop in mvc 4](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2012/09/ajax-multiple-file-upload-script-with.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery ajax upload file in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428296/jquery-ajax-upload-file-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 76):

Here is my small working sample, which uploads multiple files and uploads in a folder called as 'junk'

**Client Side....**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Upload Example</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.intellisense.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Upload").click(function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var totalFiles = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++)
            {
                var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[i];

                formData.append("FileUpload", file);
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Home/Upload',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('succes!!');
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("errror");
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="FileUpload" multiple />
    <input type="button" id="Upload" value="Upload" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Server Side....**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Upload( )
    {
        for( int i = 0 ; i < Request.Files.Count ; i++ )
        {
            var file = Request.Files[i];

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName( file.FileName );

            var path = Path.Combine( Server.MapPath( "~/Junk/" ) , fileName );
            file.SaveAs( path );    
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing work - I've tried for months to get this to work. Many thanks!

Comment: Your code uploads the file successfully, but I always get "errror". My question is how to send the response from the controller to the ajax call?

Comment: Thanks for this. @shadi1024 to return a success result change the Upload action method signature to return an ActionResult and then return a Json result e.g. return Json(new { result = "some_info" });

Comment: Man, wish I came across this earlier! Best'est answer on Internet!

Answer (score -2):

This article helped me out: http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/
The ActionResult is still `ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file) {...}`

Answer (score -4):

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Upload( )
    {
        for( int i = 0 ; i < Request.Files.Count ; i++ )
        {
            var file = Request.Files[i];

            var fileName = Path.GetFileName( file.FileName );

            var path = Path.Combine( Server.MapPath( "~/Junk/" ) , fileName );
            file.SaveAs( path );    
        }

    }
```