# Adding file to the database

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to add file to my database but for some reason its not working can someone tell me why. This is what I've sofa:

```
        $(document).on("click", "#BUTTON", function () {
        var FILE= $('#name').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "@Url.Action("File", "Controller")",
            data: JSON.stringify(FILE),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {

        }
    });
    });
```

This is what happens in my controller:

```
public ActionResult File(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/path"), pic);
            // file is uploaded
            file.SaveAs(path);

            // save the image path path to the database or you can send image 
            // directly to database
            // in-case if you want to store byte[] ie. for DB
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
            }

        }
        // after successfully uploading redirect the user
        return Index();
    }
}
```

When I place a brakepoint in line `HttpPostedFileBase file` then file has null value I dont know why? If i do `alert(FILE);` then I am getting full file path e.g. G:/filename/imagename.jpg but in controller the path is no being passed?

Comment: `.val()`  only returns string name of file. @Steven , not true, there are ajax methods for uploading

Comment: @Steven You can upload files using ajax. Maybe in older browsers it won't work, but newer ones are able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you will use files collection of your input, so try it. And i hope it will help

```
$(document).on("click", "#BUTTON", function(){

//Create form data
var data = new FormData(); 

//attach your file
data.append('file', document.getElementById("fileHere").files[0]); 

//and send it on server
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("File", "Controller")",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: When I run the code I get error message `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'files' of undefined or null reference`. In this line `            data.append('file', document.getElementById("#name").files[0]);
`

Comment: getElementById() using DOM not Jquery selector. So remove # and just type id like this document.getElementById("name")

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to post a file that way, the only thing you do is post the text value, in this case the file name.

Maybe this can help you out ([another example on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420828/file-upload-using-mvc-4-with-ajax))