# HttpPostedFile.ContentLength is always -2 after uploading files through jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, ashx

I have strange problem with jQuery AJAX and ASHX behavior. Here is my code:

```
<input type="file"  ID="FileUpload1"  multiple="multiple" />
<input type="button" ID="Button1"  Text="Upload Selected File(s)" />
```

```js
function Upload() {
    var data = new FormData();
    jQuery.each($('#FileUpload1')[0].files, function (i, file) {
        data.append('file-' + i, file);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/basic/fileupload/FileUploadHandler.ashx",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: data,
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Erro no envio de fotos do projecto. " + data.status);
        }
    });
}
```

```csharp
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    try
    {
        string dirFullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/MediaUploader/");
        string[] files;
        int numFiles;
        files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath);
        numFiles = files.Length;
        numFiles = numFiles + 1;
        string str_image = "";

        foreach (string s in context.Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[s];
            string fileName = file.FileName;
            string fileExtension = file.ContentType;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            {
                fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                str_image = "MyPHOTO_" + numFiles.ToString() + fileExtension;
                string pathToSave_100 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/files/") + str_image;
                file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100);
            }
        }
        //  database record update logic here  ()

        context.Response.Write(str_image);
    }
    catch (Exception ac)
    {
    }
}
```

Eeverything seems to be fine, but the result is:

```
context.Request.Files[0]
{System.Web.HttpPostedFile}
    ContentLength: -2
    ContentType: "image/png"
    FileName: "icon-large.png"
    InputStream: {System.Web.HttpInputStream}
```

I can receive file name but the `ContentLength` is always `-2` and after saving the file It's just `0` bytes is size. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

UPDATE :
**I've found something new , it's working fine with ASP.net Development Server (Running Application Directly by pushing F5 Key in Visual Studio) but something is wrong with IIS 8.5 configuration**

also My web.config request length parameters are :

```
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="10240000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="10240000" />
```

UPDATE 2: 
**changing Application pool's to Managed pipeline mode to Classic will solve the problem , but I will loose my URL Rewriting, so I can't change my Pipeline Mode. Any Idea?**

Comment: have tried to print data between: jQuery.each($()) and  $.ajax({})

Comment: Here is my Request :POST http://localhost/FileUploadHandler.ashx HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 338630
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMg4rlBFcHS4txlHr
Referer: http://localhost/car-information.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6

------WebKitFormBoundaryMg4rlBFcHS4txlHr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-0"; filename="icon-large.png"
Content-Type: image/png

Comment: and also my Content-Length is 338630 . I used fiddler to check my request

Comment: It may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684689/request-files-is-always-null

Comment: It seems it's not the solution  , but after changing contentType to 'json' the context.Request.ContentLength is 338630 but  context.Request.Files is empty : {System.Web.HttpFileCollection}
    base {System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase}: {System.Web.HttpFileCollection}
    AllKeys: {string[0]}

Comment: I've found something new , it's working fine with ASP.net Development Server (Running Application Directly by pushing F5 Key in Visual Studio) but something is wrong with IIS 8.5 configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to solve this problem. I don't know is it fine or not but solved my case :

I  used

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

in

> global.asax

file to manage request because the contents is visible there correctly. 
Any other Idea?