# How to use value from Jquery to Html helper razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, variables, razor

> in JavaScript

```
   <script>
           var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", '@Url.Action("****", "****")',true);

           xmlHttpRequest.onloadend = function() {
               @{
                     var res = (UserResponseMvc) TempData["UserResponse"];  
                }
                @Html.ShowAlert(res?.Message)
           }

           xmlHttpRequest.send();
   </script>
```

> in Controller

```
public ActionResult Upload() {
       //code

        TempData["UserResponse"] = new UserResponseMvc
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = "Upload Success"
        };

        return View();

}
```

In this piece, the code does not know the `res` variable.

How can I use the `res` variable here?

I write in Asp.net Mvc code.

Pls help me.

Comment: `@Html` is razor code. Its parsed on the server before its sent to the view. `res` is a client side variable which does not exist at that point. Assign your message to a view model property, not a javscript variable

Answer (score 0):

I think that can not happen
ShowAlert if only the function displays the message, then it should be a function of javascript.

> You can't. and the reason is that they do not "live" in the same time.
>   The Razor variables are "Server side variables" and they don't exist
>   anymore after the page was sent to the "Client side".
>
> When the server get a request for a view, it creates the view with
>   only HTML, CSS and Javascript code. No C# code is left, it's all get
>   "translated" to the client side languages.
>
> The Javascript code DO exist when the view is still on the server, but
>   it's meaningless and will be executed by the browser only (Client side
>   again).
>
> This is why you can use Razor variables to change the HTML and
>   Javascript but not vice versa. Try to look at your page source code
>   (CTRL+U in most browsers), there will be no sign of C# code there.
>
> In short:
>
> 1. The server get a request.
> 2. The server creates "takes" the view, compute and translate all the C# code that was embedded in the view, to CSS,Javascript, and HTML.
> 3. The server returns the client side version of the view to the browser as a response to the request.
> 4. the browser renders the page and executes all the Javascripts

Refer to [How to pass a value to razor variable from javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317182/how-to-pass-a-value-to-razor-variable-from-javascript-variable)

In your case, I have a some documents for you refer.

[jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

[File upload using MVC 4 with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420828/file-upload-using-mvc-4-with-ajax)

Comment: When uploaded, it displays an alert but does not display the value inside the message variable. Then, when I refresh the page and upload it, it displays the value inside the message variable.
I tested it with both **ViewBag** and **TempData**, but did not.
  Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: I use XMLHttpRequest for upload and can not be refreshed. This is because it does not display the value inside the Message variable. Do you have a way to solve this problem because I do not want to refresh the page.

Comment: I think you should use ajax, just like @Ali Soltani guided

Comment: I have edited the post please see.
**XmlHttpRequest** is easier to upload than **Ajax**. Of course, in my opinion.

Comment: Try it here, maybe it will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428296/jquery-ajax-upload-file-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You can like this:

**View**

```
<input type="button" value="ClickToSend" onclick="sendToAction()" />

<script>
    function sendToAction() {
        var res = ["Upload1", "Upload2", "Upload3"]; // Sample

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Upload")", // Upload is your action in controller
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(res),
            success: function (data) { alert(data); },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(List<String> res)
{
   return View();
}
```