# Post `<input type='file' />` array

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs

I have an `<input type='file' />` array of attachments that I post to an API, but I'm getting the `files` array param empty, what am I missing? Am I declaring the correct type (`IEnumerable<IFormFileCollection> files`) on the api?

The query string parameters are passing fine.

```
const  attachments  = Array.from(fileList);

const files = attachments;

const result = await apiPost(`api/attachments/addAttachments?request=${request}&&ticketId=${ticketId}`, files, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    });
```

And the API:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("attachments")]
public async Task<string> addAttachments(string request, int ticketId, [FromBody]IEnumerable<IFormFileCollection> files)
{...}
```

[image]

`apiPost`:

```
import { AdalConfig, adalFetch } from 'react-adal';

export const apiFetch: <T>(url: string, options?: object) => Promise<T> = (
  url: string,
  options: object,
) => adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api, axios, url, options);

export const apiPost = async <T>(url: string, data: object): Promise<T> => {
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    data,
    config: {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    },
  };
  return apiFetch(url, options);
};
```

Comment: Is this angular?

Comment: @Liam no, it's not

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post

Comment: It is possible that I see this the wrong way but `Array.from(fileList)` does not return an object that could be destructured using `{ attachments }`.

Comment: What’s `apiPost`?

Comment: @Ry- please see my edited question.

Comment: `apiPost` takes two  arguments, and the only place you’re passing `files` is as the third argument…?

Comment: What's `adalFetch`?! Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem

Comment: @Ry- I removed the first parameter and now just trying to pass the `files` array but it still comes up empty

Comment: @Liam Please see my edited question.

Comment: So this is a react application then?! It would really, really help if you'd actually explain what technology your trying to use here instead of drip feeding pieces of information into the question..Not to mention that this seems to be the third iteration of this question you've asked.

Comment: try [FromForm] instead of [FromBody] in the API files variable

Comment: Your content type is wrong, you need to use `multipart/form-data` to upload files. You can't upload files using `application/json` it doesn't support file uploading. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233528/how-to-do-a-rest-api-post-request-with-fileupload-to-an-azure-ad-protected-rest/51319039) seems to cover everything you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the above comments (especially thanks to @Liam for the excellent example he referred me to) I was able to figure it out:

```
const files = { ...attachments };

const data = new FormData();
// Append files to form data
for (let i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
  data.append('files', files[i], files[i].name);
}

const { result } = apiPost(`api/attachments/addAttachments?request=${request}&ticketId=${ticketId}`, data, {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
});
```

I changed the `apiPost` method to get a `header` param:

```
export const apiPost = async <T>(url: string, data: object, headers: object): Promise<T> => {
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    data,
    config: {
      headers: headers || {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    },
  };
  console.log(data);
  console.log(options);
  return apiFetch(url, options);
};
```

And finally the api controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("attachments")]
public async Task<string> addAttachments(string request, int ticketId, IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
```