# Ajax how to pass array it has file list (.NET CORE / AJAX / JQUERY)

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I have a array in jquery. And i have a file list in view.
I want to put this file list into my array and pass my controller/action
I find some ways but dont work.
there is my jquery

````
var Data = new FormData();
        $('input[data-fileid=1]').each(function () {
            var FileData = $(this).get(0).files[0];
            Data.append("Attachments", FileData);
        });
        var arr = {
            Code: "examplecode",
            Id: 1
            FileList: Data
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: JSON.stringify(arr),
            url: '/Panel/PD',
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        });```

and I don't know how to keep this data in class.
````

Comment: I can not follow you. Can you explain it more detailed. Why are you using $('input[data-fileid=1]').each you have only one element. Can you post the html.

Comment: it doesn't matter. I can receive files, but I don't know how to send them. I want to embed it in the class.

Answer (score 0):

When sending binary file data in an AJAX request you cannot send data as a serialised string. It needs to be contained within a `FormData` object.

From there, you need to set the `contentType` and `processData` to `false` within the `$.ajax()` settings so that jQuery doesn't attempt to change the request content or the content-type header. Try this:

```js
var Data = new FormData();
Data.append('Code', 'examplecode');
Data.append('Id', 1);

$('input[data-fileid=1]').each(function() {
  var FileData = $(this).get(0).files[0];
  Data.append("Attachments", FileData);
});

$.ajax({
  url: '/Panel/PD',
  type: 'POST',
  data: Data,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false, 
  success: response => {
    console.log('handle the response here...');
  }
});
```

On the server side you can use the `Request.Files` collection to iterate through the file data in the request as normal - assuming you haven't extended the default ModelBinder to receive binary data.

Also note that a simpler way to build the `FormData` object is to pass a reference to the `form` element to the constructor. All data within the controls of the form will then be appended to the object. If you want to append custom data to this, use hidden `input` controls within the HTML.

```
var data = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
```

This avoids the need to manually `append()` any magic strings in your JS logic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So how am I going to keep this "Attachments" on the controller side?

Comment: You don't need to; use `Request.Files` and iterate through it. If you need to retain the original filename it can be read from `Requets.Files[i].FileName`

Comment: An example which may help is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37762290/519413

Comment: I have to send a series of content in addition to the file. As far as I understand it is just to send files that you wrote.

Comment: The answer I linked to does yes, however you can see in the example above that I use `append()` to add additional data to the `FormData` object in the request

Answer (score -1):

So your ajax should send data that required in controller,

```
$.ajax({ 
            url: '/Panel/PD',
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      traditional: true, // required to send an array on controller
      data: { 'arrayOfValues': JSON.stringify(arr)} ,
      error: function() { console.log('lets track error here'); } // check if you get any error 

             
 });
```

Controlller will look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public void PD(List<string> arrayOfValues) //should get your files data here
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot send form data in a JSON formatted request.